# Apache HTML5 not showing?

Tags: php, html, apache

I'm using latest Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and I installed Apache and PHP.
I have some problems with PHP and HTML5 documents.

If I navigate localhost/PHPTest.php my browser is blank.
However, if I remove lines `<!DOCTYPE html>` AND `<meta charset="UTF-8">` I can see my webpage. Why I cannot use those lines? How I can fix this?

This example do not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>This is not working</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is not working</p>
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This one works:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>This works</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This works!</p>
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I bet you're just looking at the rendered page. Do some basic debugging: see actual source code (in Firefox you reach it with `Ctrl+U`) and check Apache and PHP logs for error messages. And don't forget to clear browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

just re-install lamp using below codes

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2

sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql

sudo mysql_install_db
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

The prompt will ask you for your current root password.
Type it in.
 Then the prompt will ask you if you want to change the root password. Go ahead and choose N and move on to the next steps.

It’s easiest just to say Yes to all the options. At the end, MySQL will reload and implement the new changes.

```
Remove anonymous users? [Y/n] y                                    

Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n] y

Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n] y

Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n] y
```

Now

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt

sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

Add index.php to the beginning of index files. The page should now look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>

      DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php 
index.xhtml index.htm

</IfModule>

to save this press ctrl+x and type y then enter
```

Save and exit

Now

```
apt-cache search php5-
```

Terminal will then display the list of possible modules. The beginning looks like this:

```
php5-cgi - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
php5-cli - command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
php5-common - Common files for packages built from the php5 source
php5-curl - CURL module for php5
php5-dbg - Debug symbols for PHP5
php5-dev - Files for PHP5 module development
php5-gd - GD module for php5
php5-gmp - GMP module for php5
php5-ldap - LDAP module for php5
php5-mysql - MySQL module for php5
php5-odbc - ODBC module for php5
php5-pgsql - PostgreSQL module for php5
php5-pspell - pspell module for php5
php5-recode - recode module for php5
php5-snmp - SNMP module for php5
php5-sqlite - SQLite module for php5
php5-tidy - tidy module for php5
php5-xmlrpc - XML-RPC module for php5
php5-xsl - XSL module for php5
php5-adodb - Extension optimising the ADOdb database abstraction library
php5-auth-pam - A PHP5 extension for PAM authentication
[...]
```

Although LAMP is installed, we can still take a look and see the components online by creating a quick php info page

To set this up, first create a new file:

```
sudo nano /var/www/info.php
```

Add in the following line:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>

to save this press ctrl+x and type y then enter
```

Then Save and Exit.

Now install phpmyadmin package

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

then

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then add the following line at the end:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

save and exit

Restart apache so that all of the changes take effect:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now u will be able to use html5

Comment: This answer could use an explanation of why you need a full reinstall of a complete LAMP stack (MySQL and PhpMyAdmin included) to fix such a vague symptom as a blank page...

Comment: there may be some issues in lamp installation i have installed lamp in ubuntu 14.04 itself and i am able to use those lines

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 17.10.

I got PHP scripts to work within HTML5 code running on an apache2 server 
by installing packages

- mysql-server
- php7.0
- libapache2-mod-php7.1

and by adding lines to the file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.1.conf

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.html$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

and by restarting apache2 server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```